# Browserify: External Hash ID Keeps Changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, gruntjs, browserify

I'm using Grunt-Browserify to load a library (jQuery) in one bundle and reference that library as `external` in other bundles.

Browserify assigns a unique hash id to the external library, and everything works fine for a single developer.

However, when a second developer runs the same Grunt task, the unique id for jQuery changes -- breaking any bundles that are still looking for it at the old "address".

Does anyone know how to control the id assigned to an external library in Browserify -- or how to prevent Browserify from using a hash id for external dependencies?

Here's my current configuration:

```
browserify: {

  main: {
    files: {
      './dist/main.js': ['./dev/js/main.js']
    },
    options: {
      require: ['jquery'],
      fullPaths: true,
      watch: true
    }
  },

  bundles: {
    files: {
      './dist/bundle-1.js': ['./dev/bundle-1.js'],
      // ...
    },
    options: {
      external: ['jquery'],
      fullPaths: true,
      watch: true
    }
  }
}
```